# Angular models should i make attributes private and a constructor?

Tags: angular

i know that normally it is best practice to make attributes private and make getters and setters however what i see on tutorials online is that models, are done this way:

```
export class UserModel{
   name: string,
}
```

should i make it this way:

```
export class UserModel{
   private name: string;
   constructor(name){ this.name = name}
   getName(){ return this.name}
   setName(name) { this.name = name}
```

Which is a better practice for Angular, note that when i worked with the first its much easier when working alongside services etc.

Comment: typical use cases for getter/setter is you have extra logic, e.g. `get name() {return this.firstName+ this.lastName; } ` or audit such actions to log system.  otherwise, public accessor is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally define an interface instead of a class with just the properties:

```
export interface UserModel{
   name: string;
}
```

I only use getters/setters if I need some logic in the getter/setter OR if the value is coming from somewhere else (such as a service) and I want to ensure I always have the most recent value.

Here I want to ensure that the bound `searchTerm` is updated in the service. And if another component updates the service, that I always get the current value from that service.

```
  get searchTerm(): string {
    return this.dataService.serviceData;
  }

  set searchTerm(value: string) {
    this.dataService.serviceData = value;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I now know interfaces are used to define the shape of an object, while classes are used to make multiple instances or singleton. However let say me and my friends still not comfortable enough to work with interfaces and we're halfway through the project. Thus we're using classes, so as a second best solution should i make the class attributes private or public, knowing i only want to define the shape of that object only.

Comment: Depending on how concerned you are about mutating state, and especially if the team is so new that interfaces are uncomfortable, I'd go with public properties and just define proper setters/getters (using the TypeScript syntax, not the functions) if they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use accessors mutators

Follow below.

http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/javascript-getters-setters-typescript-accessor-tutorial/

Comment: Right! So it is better to make them private.

Comment: We must follow the Typescript syntax as that is easy to use and generate from ide plus it encloses the actual variable protecting it.